# What is the best way to make a Jetty server do something before shutting down?

Tags: java, jetty, hook

I have a Jetty server that is being initialized and started like this:

```
    Server server = new Server(50001); 

    MyHandler myHandler = new MyHandler();
    server.setHandler(myHandler);


    // attempt to run the server
    try {
        server.start();
        server.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.warning(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(2);
    }
```

The class `MyHandler` has a method called `shutdown` that waits for tasks to be complete. I would like `myHandler.shutdown()` to be invoked before the server is shutdown.

I have considered using `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()`, but I am not sure of the best way to pass `myHandler` to it, and I suspect that there must be a cleaner way to do this.

I am looking for the best way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the handler chain down and you'll see it runs into AbstractLifeCycle that defines some methods called doStart() and doStop().  You can override these to plug into the lifecycle of the server instance since you are adding yourself as a handler to the server.  This works generally for anything that either extends AbstractLifeCycle or implements Lifecycle, making it a handy mechanism to register start and stop type behaviors.  The doStart() would be called  in the processing of server.start() and the doStop() is called during the processing of the server.stop() call.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. It seemed like it would work, but unfortunately, it does not seem to be calling doStop(): protected void doStop() throws Exception {
     System.out.println("OK");
 
     super.doStop();
 }

Comment: ```protected void doStop()``` should probably be ```public```, not ```protected```

Comment: they are not meant to be called directly, that is start() and stop() which end up initiating the lifecycle handling of the registered components and call their do*() methods